# Consciousness and Spacetime

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, time, souls, space

What is consciousness?

Is our conceived perception a part of space or time?

Can we be conscious in a state where time is non existent, or frozen?

Is consciousness energy?

Does it adhere to physical laws of conservation?

Comment: I edited your post to emphasize the questions. You may roll this back or continue editing.  You can see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link above. There are many questions here. Each might be worth a post. If you add a reference to some philosophic position to give each question context it would help the person writing an answer to better respond.  If this does get closed because it is too broad, try again with something else.  Welcome to this SE!

Comment: Our policy is one question per post, and you need to provide context and narrow the scope for asking here. Broad and vague questions like "What is consciousness?" are better addressed by reading encyclopedias, e.g. [Wikipedia's Consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness).

Comment: Try reading all these words in the same instant instead of one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Stuart Hammeroff thinks consciousness, or mental structure, is not just a network of neurons but microtubules on the surfaces of neurons which in turn are connected by entangled quantum states - and these quantum states could exist independently of the brain (after the brain has whipped them into shape).  Here is an excerpt from a 2011 interview.

> I’ve been asked basically if it’s possible that consciousness can
>   exist outside the brain in the case when the brain has stopped being
>   perfused and the heart has stopped and so forth. I think we can’t rule
>   it out. I think it’s possible because in the model that Penrose and I
>   developed-and I should say this is my speculation and Roger wouldn’t
>   go there-but I would say that since consciousness is happening it
>   seems to us at the level of spacetime geometry, the most fundamental
>   level of the universe, or at least down to that level in the brain in
>   and around the microtubules, right now while we’re conscious, while
>   we’re talking.
>
> If that’s the case then when the brain stops functioning some of this
>   quantum information might not be lost or dissipated or destroyed but
>   could persist in some way in this fundamental level of spacetime
>   geometry which it seems is not local and something like holographic
>   repeating in scale and distances and persists perhaps even
>   indefinitely at a finer scale, which would be a higher frequency,
>   smaller scale but also lower energy. And it could exist somewhat
>   indefinitely.

https://skeptiko.com/stuart-hameroff-on-quantum-consciousness-and-singularity/

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to understand my answer you should know the limitations of the answers to these types of questions regarding consciousness, because when strictly speaking this is not something to be understood like other ideas.  This answer is just for guiding you to a rational thought.

Some philosophies had already declared that our real nature is consciousness.  And many wise persons have realized this truth.  They realized that their real nature is nothing more than consciousness.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aham_Brahmasmi

When they realized themselves they realized the real nature of their fellow beings and everything else.  So in anybody's case, one can't measure the depth of consciousness.  (Please remember the parable of the salt doll of Sriramakrishna.)

```
"Once a salt doll went to measure the depth of the ocean. It wanted to tell others how deep the water was. But this it could never do, for no sooner did it get into the water than it dissolved. Now, who was there to report the ocean's depth? What Brahman is cannot be described. In samadhi one attains the knowledge of Brahman -- one realises Brahman. In that state reasoning stops altogether, and man becomes mute. He has no power to describe the nature of Brahman."
```

> What is consciousness?

From your questions I understand your question is something apart from each individual's physical nature.  So, please refer the following links also to know more about some aspects of Consciousness.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_(consciousness)

https://www.yogapedia.com/definition/5412/chaitanya

> Is our conceived perception a part of space or time?

Perception is the ability to see, hear, or become aware of something **through the senses**.  So this is related to space and time.

> Can we be conscious in a state where time is non existent, or frozen?

Yes.  When you realize the truth you will experience this.

> Is consciousness energy?

You may have heard of the parable ['Blind men and an elephant'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant).  Like those blind men we also try to confine it as Energy -- The ability to do work.  But the truth is beyond this.

> Does it adhere to physical laws of conservation?

Actually we took only particular aspects of consciousness and termed 'Physical'.  And we already know about its conservation (Law of conservation of energy, conservation of linear momentum, conservation of angular momentum, and conservation of electric charge)...this is only its one aspect.  I mean, we cannot (or don't know how to) calculate the conservation of all the complements of those physical aspects.  But we can ensure (or believe) that it has nothing to lose or gain because if it is not so, we will have to consider a second thing. Rational thought could lead you to think about the possibility of a second thing.  But experience, ... **Never**; if it is about consciousness.  You will be compelled to believe in another consciousness that is helping you for your rational thought about consciousness.  That is why I saying so.
To confirm this, you could remember what you read in the first link.